# jquery mobile list view styles doesnt apply style after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, listview, jquery-mobile-listview

List view doesnt apply any style, it only shwowing me the html codes. I have tried most of the solutions that i can find online. Still unable to get it work. i'm not sure if it's the jquery version issue, im using 1.3.1.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    data: JSON.stringify({ userid: userid }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",


    success: function (response) {


        $.each(response.d, function (index, Record) {

         var loanListDiv = "";
         loanListDiv += "<li><a href='loanInfo.html'>" + Record.loanid + "<span>" + Record.status + "</span></a></li>";


         $("#result").append(loanListDiv);
         $("#result").trigger("create");



        });
```

Below are the codes i tried

```
$("#result").listview();

$("#result").listview("refresh");

$("#result ul").listview("refresh");

$('#result').append($(loanListDiv));

$("ul").collapsibleset("refresh");

$("#result").append(loanListDiv).listview("refresh");
```

My list view only showing one list after adding the codes above. I have about 20 lists

Answer (score 0):

Refresh the list just after you updated your HTML. Something like:

```
$("#result12344").append(loanListDiv).listview("refresh");
```

try this,

```
success: function (response) {
  var loanListDiv = "";
  $.each(response.d, function (index, Record) {
    loanListDiv += "<li><a href='loanInfo.html'>" + Record.loanid + "<span>" + Record.status + "</span></a></li>";
 });
 $("#result12344").append(loanListDiv).listview('refresh');
 $("#result12344").trigger("create");
```

Comment: I tired, but it doesn't work     $("#result12344").append(loanListDiv).listview("refresh");

Comment: Updated. Please try again.

Comment: same problem. i have about 20 lists, but it's only showing one without listview style. Thanks for the help though!